# PostgreSQL select sum inside procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I want a procedure that checks, which buyer spent more than 1600$ and than I want to print out their info, so I could send them a gift card.
I get error: *SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data*
when I call this procedure:

```
create or replace procedure bookstore.procedure1 () 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    i integer := 0;
    temp_price numeric;
    temp_sum numeric;
    temp_foreign_key integer;
    number_of_buyers integer := (select count(*) from bookstore.buyer);
    
begin
    
    while i < number_of_buyers loop
        
        select sum (price) as temp_sum from bookstore.receipt where id_buyer = i;
        
        if temp_sum > 1600 then
            select id_buyer, name, surname, adress from bookstore.buyer where id_buyer = i;
        end if;
        i := i+1;
        
    end loop;

end

$$;
```

The problem is in *select sum (price) as temp_sum...* row. I have the similar procedure in MySQL and it works. I tried running that row with id_buyer = 20 for example and it worked. How should I change it?

That's my first question on stackoverflow, I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Let SQL do all the work of serving the data. This can be done in a single statement.

```
select buy.buy_id
     , buy.name  
     , buy.address 
     , buy.city      
     , buy.postal_code 
     , pur.purchases
  from buyers   buy
  join ( select inv.buy_id 
              , sum(inv.amount)  purchases
           from invoices inv
          group by buy_id
          having sum(inv.amount) >= 1600.00          
       ) pur
    on (pur.buy_id = buy.buy_id) ;
```

If you *must* have a stored program, then wrap the above query in a SQL function that returns a table. then Select from the function.

```
create or replace 
function preferred_buyers()
  returns table ( buy_id   integer  
                , name     text 
                , address  text
                , city     text
                , postal_code text
                , purchases numeric(7,2)
                ) 
   language sql
as $$
    select buy.buy_id
         , buy.name  
         , buy.address 
         , buy.city      
         , buy.postal_code 
         , pur.purchases
      from buyers   buy
      join ( select inv.buy_id 
                  , sum(inv.amount)  purchases
               from invoices inv
              group by buy_id
              having sum(inv.amount) >= 1600.00          
           ) pur
        on (pur.buy_id = buy.buy_id) ;
$$;  

select * from preferred_buyers();
```

Neither of the above handles printing task. This is not something SQL very good at. Actually it cannot do so. Printing requires a programming language extension; for Postgres it is `plpgsql`. Also realize any printing done is not available at least in a production environment; it would be on the DB server. Handle your printing in the presentation manager (app).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the **return statement**

In the Function creation definition SQL, there must be a row written as  **RETURNS integer/text**

Try-

```
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    i integer := 0;
    temp_price numeric;
    temp_sum numeric;
    temp_foreign_key integer;
    number_of_buyers integer := (select count(*) from bookstore.buyer);
    
begin
    
    while i < number_of_buyers loop
        
        select sum (price) as temp_sum from bookstore.receipt where id_buyer = i;
        
        if temp_sum > 1600 then
            select id_buyer, name, surname, adress from bookstore.buyer where id_buyer = i;
        end if;
        i := i+1;
        
    end loop;

return 1; 
end
$$;
```

Or else you can remove the initial statement of RETURNS text/integer by using **CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function ...**

Comment: The first row wasn't visible before, i corrected that now, sorry. This is a procedure. A function must have a RETURN statement (with some value) but you can't return value with RETURN in procedure. You can just write return; and that stops the procedure.
So if I try the code you suggested, there's an error because RETURN has a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In plpgsql **SELECT** statement must have a receiver.
You must redirect the **SELECT** output with **INTO** or use direct affectation

```
--Fist version
SELECT SUM(price) FROM bookstore.receipt WHERE id_buyer = i INTO temp_sum;
--Second version, keep surrounding parenthesis
temp_sum = (SELECT SUM(price) FROM bookstore.receipt WHERE id_buyer = i);
```

Regarding your loop, you should use something more efficient and safe

```
DECLARE
    temp_sum         NUMERIC;
    v_buyer          bookstore.BUYER;
BEGIN

    FOR v_buyer IN SELECT * FROM bookstore.buyer LOOP
        --Use coalesce to manage empty result
        temp_sum = (SELECT coalesce(SUM(price), 0) FROM bookstore.receipt WHERE id_buyer = v_buyer.id);

        IF temp_sum > 1600 THEN
            -- Your business logic
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END
```

If your dataset is large it's better to use a cursor

```
DECLARE
    temp_sum NUMERIC;
    v_buyer_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM bookstore.buyer;
    v_buyer  bookstore.BUYER;
BEGIN

    FOR v_buyer IN v_buyer_cursor LOOP

        temp_sum = (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) FROM bookstore.receipt WHERE id_buyer = v_buyer.id);

        IF temp_sum > 1600 THEN
            -- Your business logic
        END IF;
        
    END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped. I had to replace this row:

```
SELECT id_buyer, name, surname, adress FROM bookstore.buyer WHERE id_buyer = i;
```

with this row:

```
INSERT INTO bookstore.temp SELECT id_buyer, name, surname, adress FROM bookstore.buyer WHERE id_buyer = i;
```

Now it works.